# Error de variables indefinidas

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando insertar unos datos a la BBDD, pero me da error de variable indefinida en el index, os dejo el código por si veis algún error:

Archivo agregar:

```
<?php session_start();

$equipo = $_POST['equipo'];
$idequipo = $_POST['idequipo'];
$piloto1 = $_POST['piloto1'];
$piloto2 = $_POST['piloto2'];
$piloto3 = $_POST['piloto3'];
$piloto4 = $_POST['piloto4'];
$piloto5 = $_POST['piloto5'];
$piloto6 = $_POST['piloto6'];
$idepiloto1 = $_POST['idepiloto1'];
$idepiloto2 = $_POST['idepiloto2'];
$idepiloto3 = $_POST['idepiloto3'];
$idepiloto4 = $_POST['idepiloto4'];
$idepiloto5 = $_POST['idepiloto5'];
$idepiloto6 = $_POST['idepiloto6'];
$twitpiloto1 = $_POST['twitpiloto1'];
$twitpiloto2 = $_POST['twitpiloto2'];
$twitpiloto3 = $_POST['twitpiloto3'];
$twitpiloto4 = $_POST['twitpiloto4'];
$twitpiloto5 = $_POST['twitpiloto5'];
$twitpiloto6 = $_POST['twitpiloto6'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];



include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';

$sql_agregar = 'INSERT INTO equipos (equipo,idequipo,piloto1,piloto2,piloto3,piloto4,piloto5,piloto6,idepiloto1,idepiloto2,idepiloto3,idepiloto4,idepiloto5,idepiloto6,twitpiloto1,twitpiloto2,twitpiloto3,twitpiloto4,twitpiloto5,twitpiloto6,categoria) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    $sentencia_agregar = $pdo->prepare($sql_agregar);

    if ($sentencia_agregar->execute(array($equipo,$idequipo,$piloto1,$piloto2,$piloto3,$piloto4,$piloto5,$piloto6,$idepiloto1,$idepiloto2,$idepiloto3,$idepiloto4,$idepiloto5,$idepiloto6,$twitpiloto1,$twitpiloto2,$twitpiloto3,$twitpiloto4,$twitpiloto5,$twitpiloto6,$categoria))) {
        echo 'agregado';
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }


    //cerramos conexión base de datos y sentencia
    $sentencia_agregar = null;
    $pdo = null;
```

Archivo HTML:

```
<form action="../php/agregar_equipo.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
 <!-- Material form register -->
            <form action="../php/agregar_equipo.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">

                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                        <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <i class="fa fa-drivers-license-o prefix grey-text"></i>
                                <input type="text" name="equipo" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Equipo</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                        <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                            <div class="md-form">
                                <i class="fa fa-code-fork prefix grey-text"></i>
                                <input type="text" name="idequipo" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">ID-Equipo</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        <i class="fa fa-drivers-license-o prefix grey-text"></i>
                                        <input type="text" name="piloto1" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                        <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Piloto 1</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                    <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <i class="fa fa-code-fork prefix grey-text"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="idepiloto1" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                            <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">ID-Piloto 1</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                        <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                            <div class="md-form">
                                                <i class="fa fa-twitter prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                <input type="text" name="twitpiloto1" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" >
                                                <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Twitter Piloto 1 (opcional)</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                        </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                    <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <i class="fa fa-drivers-license-o prefix grey-text"></i>
                                            <input type="text" name="piloto2" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                            <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Piloto 2</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                        <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                            <div class="md-form">
                                                <i class="fa fa-code-fork prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                <input type="text" name="idepiloto2" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                                <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">ID-Piloto 2</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                <div class="md-form">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="twitpiloto2" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control">
                                                    <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Twitter Piloto 2 (opcional)</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                            </div>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                        <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                            <div class="md-form">
                                                <i class="fa fa-drivers-license-o prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                <input type="text" name="piloto3" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                                <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Piloto 3</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                <div class="md-form">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-code-fork prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="idepiloto3" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                                    <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">ID-Piloto 3</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-4">
                                                <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-twitter prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                        <input type="text" name="twitpiloto3" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control">
                                                        <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Twitter Piloto 3 (opcional)</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                <div class="md-form">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-drivers-license-o prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="piloto4" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control"required >
                                                    <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Piloto 4</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-4">
                                                <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-code-fork prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                        <input type="text" name="idepiloto4" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                                        <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">ID-Piloto 4</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="col-4">
                                                    <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                        <div class="md-form">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-twitter prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                            <input type="text" name="twitrpiloto4" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control">
                                                            <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Twitter Piloto 4 (opcional)</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                <div class="md-form">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-drivers-license-o prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="piloto5" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                                    <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Piloto 5</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-4">
                                                <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-code-fork prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                        <input type="text" name="idepiloto5" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                                        <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">ID-Piloto 5</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="col-4">
                                                    <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                        <div class="md-form">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-twitter prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                            <input type="text" name="twitpiloto5" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control">
                                                            <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Twitter Piloto 5 (opcional)</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                            <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                <div class="md-form">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-drivers-license-o prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" name="piloto6" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                                    <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Piloto 6</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-4">
                                                <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-code-fork prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                        <input type="text" name="idepiloto6" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control" required>
                                                        <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">ID-Piloto 6</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="col-4">
                                                    <!-- Material input Equipo -->
                                                        <div class="md-form">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-twitter prefix grey-text"></i>
                                                            <input type="text" name="twitpiloto6" id="materialFormCardNameEx" class="form-control">
                                                            <label for="materialFormCardConfirmEx" class="font-weight-light">Twitter Piloto 6 (opcional)</label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <!-- Material input categoría -->
                                <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col my-1">
              <label class="mr-sm-2 amber-text" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Categoría</label>
              <br>
              <p class="grey-text">Dependiendo de la categoria que elijas y el momento, deberás elegir la opción correcta. Ejemplo:
              Ahora mismo, se debería elegir la tercera división, dado que el campeonato empieza desde 0. El staff, reorganizará las divisiones según el reglamento. Cuando haya más divisiones,
              deberán elegir donde corresponde.
              </p>
              <select name="categoria" class="custom-select mr-sm-2 " id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                <option selected>Elige la opción</option>
                <option>Monoplazas Div 1</option>
                <option>Monoplazas Div 2</option>
                <option>Monoplazas Div 3</option>
                <option>Turismos Div 1</option>
                <option>Turismos Div 2</option>
                <option>Turismos Div 3</option>

              </select>
            </div>

                    </div>
                                </div>




                <div class="text-center py-4 mt-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning waves-effect" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
                </div>
            </form>

Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: idequipo in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\agregar_equipo.php
> on line 4
> 
> Notice: Undefined index: twitpiloto1 in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\agregar_equipo.php
> on line 17
> 
> Notice: Undefined index: twitpiloto2 in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\agregar_equipo.php
> on line 18
> 
> Notice: Undefined index: twitpiloto3 in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\agregar_equipo.php
> on line 19
> 
> Notice: Undefined index: twitpiloto4 in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\agregar_equipo.php
> on line 20
> 
> Notice: Undefined index: twitpiloto5 in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\agregar_equipo.php
> on line 21
> 
> Notice: Undefined index: twitpiloto6 in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\php\agregar_equipo.php
> on line 22 error
```

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda que mostraras el error completo ya que generalmente la solución esta en el error.

Comment: Edita y mostrando error.

Comment: tienes un error en el Twitter Piloto 4: Atributo `name` en formulario: twitrpiloto4` y en` PHP` tienes : twitpiloto4, verifica eso y me avisas, luego que corregí eso me funciono todo lo demas.

Comment: cómo envías los datos? dónde está el form? es ajax? un post de un form a otra página?
lo del atributo que te comentan solo te quitaría un error, no todos

Comment: falta la etiqueta `<form>` de apertura?

Comment: perdonad, me había comido el form que si estaba puesto en mi documento. He corregido lo del twitter pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

primeramente no veo la etiqueta **form** de apertura varifica que el methodo en verdad sea **POST** y este otro error podria ser la causa tienes varieda en el atributo name y la variable que lo recive de  **twitpiloto4**

```
$twitpiloto4 = $_POST['twitpiloto4'];

 name="twitrpiloto4"
```

saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno aparte de que debes verificar que todos los nombres de tu form son correctos y que tu formulario se este enviando en el método **POST**. En tu php **agregar_equipo.php** te hace falta `isset()` para verificar que los parámetros están definidos.

```
if(isset($_POST['equipo'])){ 
   $equipo = $_POST['equipo']; 
}
if(isset($_POST['idequipo']){
  $idequipo = $_POST['idequipo'];
}
if(isset($_POST['idequipo']){
  $piloto1 = $_POST['idequipo'];
}
```

Y así deberías hacerlo con todos los que tengas, de esta manera ya no te enviara el mensaje

```
Notice: Undefined index: idequipo in
```